# Hostile mobs spawning rules on PS4?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I found a skeleton monster spawner and build a xp trap around it.
It's the typical trap described in all the YouTube videos:

[image: Minecraft Trap Tutorial]
**Source:** [YouTube Tutorial by KaspersMC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8blg0dH-PE) (this picture *doesn't* show the final trap)

The trap *works* and I wanted to extend it, so that also other hostile mobs get caught. Therefore I added two more rooms that look exactly like this one but *without* water (because I read something about hostile mobs can't spawn - besides by a monster spawner - on flowing water? Is that true?).

**Rooms:**

- completely dark
- all cobblestone
- 9x9x3 (LxWxH, at some points even a height of 4 blocks)
- tested with and without water

**Problem:** Other mobs (but skeletons from the mob spawner) don't spawn. Neither in the two new rooms nor in the first one.

I already tried to go more than 24 blocks away, wait some time and then come back to check the rooms but they were still empty!

I checked during day and night.

**Questions:**

1. Can other hostile mobs spawn near mob spawners in general?
2. Can hostile mobs spawn on floating water?

---

**Platform:** PS4 Pro
**Version:** 1.74
**Mode:** Survival, single-player
**Difficulty:** Normal

Answer (score 2):

Spawning rules on Bedrock edition are the same for the most part.

For your case relevant are the following rules:

Hostile overworld mobs do not spawn when:

- The Block checked for spawning is an air block (unless spawned by a spawner)
- there is no space for the hitbox of a mob
- there block height is not a full block (e.g. carpet, snowlayers, slabs)
- light level is >=7
- water or lava on the block (either source block or flowing)